# Django does not exit after finishing tests when using threading module

Tags: python, django, bash, python-multithreading, django-testing

I am doing integration tests using `django.test.SimpleTestCase`.
After running `python manage.py test`, the tests run successfully and the terminal hangs with the message:

```
---------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 1.365s

OK
```

The problem is that currently I go back to the terminal using CTRL+C, but I want to have automated tests in my CI/CD pipeline.

Did I do something wrong in the way I executed the tests? Or is this behaviour normal? In this case, is there an way in Bash to programatically execute and then exit the tests?

**EDIT:**
After analysing my app in depth, I was able to identify what was causing that behaviour. I am using `threading` in a way like the following in my `views.py`:

```
def __pooling():
  wait_time = 10
  call_remote_server()
  threading.Timer(wait_time, __pooling).start()

__pooling()
```

Basically I need that my application do something from time to time asynchronously.
Should I change the way I am doing the pooling? Or should I disable it (how?) during the tests?

Comment: When the tests are done you should get back to your terminal automatically. Are you doing anything besides `python manage.py test`? What operating system are you on? Are you using Docker or a VM of some kind?

Comment: Yes I am only doing `python manage.py test`. Running in a ubuntu 18.0.4 VM. Also using virtualenv.

Comment: How long are you waiting before hitting Ctrl+C? Are you using the regular default bash shell, or something else?

Comment: Yes the default bash. I just used bash -c `"python manage.py test"` and had the same result. It´s been 5 minutes and it didn't exit.

Comment: That does sound weird. Please try running [`python manage.py test -v 2`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-verbosity) or even `-v 3` to increase verbosity. Hopefully there's something interesting in that output.

Comment: The verbosity didn´t increase at all with -v 2 or -v 3

Comment: Can you attach a debugger to your tests? Your IDE might be able to do this, or something like [`django-pdb`](https://github.com/HassenPy/django-pdb).

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've identified what is causing that behaviour and edited my post. But now I am unsure how can I exit my tests while using multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was able to identify what was causing that behaviour. I am using `threading` in a way like the following in my `views.py`:
>
> ```
> def __pooling():
>   wait_time = 10
>   call_remote_server()
>   threading.Timer(wait_time, __pooling).start()
>
> __pooling()
> ```
>
> Basically I need that my application do something from time to time
>   asynchronously. Should I change the way I am doing the pooling?

I don't fully understand your needs, but a more traditional approach would be to schedule a task (probably a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)) outside of Django itself. An OS-level scheduler like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), something like [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or a task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) would all be reasonable choices.

> Or should I disable it (how?) during the tests?

I don't recommend continuing to use your `__pooling()` function as it exists today. In my opinion this kind of thing doesn't belong in your `views.py`. But if you want to keep it, something like

```
from django.conf import settings

if not settings.DEBUG:
  __pooling()
```

might help. Your `__pooling()` function would only be called when `DEBUG` is falsy, as it should be in production. (If it is also falsy in your CI environment you could choose another existing setting, or add something to your `settings.py` specifically to control this.)

Comment: Thank you a lot Chris! I will have a look on schedulers and task queues. The DEBUG is also an elegant workaround.

Comment: Happy to help, @VictorVal. Good luck!